# Is it possible to write a complex sentence without a dependent clause and without conjunctions?

Tags: sentence-structure, subordinate-clauses

My first language is *not* English. I am currently preparing for the IELTS exam. Today I saw a YouTube video about the IELTS writing task. In this video, the teacher gave an example of a complex sentence which is:

> "The amount of people from an English town deciding to start a
>   vegetarian diet increased steadily by approximately 125 from about 75
>   to 200 between 2004 and 2007. "

In another video, the teacher gave some more examples of complex sentences:

> Between 2004 and 2007, the number of people increased steadily from
>   about 75 to 200.
>
> There was a steady increase in the number of people from about 75 to
>   200 between 2004 and 2007.
>
> The number of people becoming vegetarian experienced a steady increase
>   from about 75 to 200 between 2004 and 2007.

I myself *cannot* see any subordinate clause or dependent clause in the *four* sentences. *I do not know why are they considered **complex sentences**.* Can anyone help me ASAP please? My IELTS exam is very near :(.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know what the "technical" definition of a complex sentence is... but that first one, particularly, seems ridiculously complex and poorly worded to boot. And I honestly can't get past the use of "amount"... which I find really unacceptable.

Comment: The number of people also cannot "increase *steadily by approximately 125*".  That's like saying "The car's speed increased steadily by 40 mph from 20mph to 60mph."

Comment: The first video comes from a Spanish language site, and is part of a lesson on _infinitives and gerunds_; complex sentences are not mentioned! The second is [here](http://ieltsliz.com/ielts-writing-task-1-line-graph-sentences/), and there are  **important lessons** which precede it and give context, but they have been removed from Liz's site and "will be replaced later." However, the lesson is clear enough as it is.

Comment: As a note, cross posting identical questions on different sites is strongly discouraged. Please pick which site you'd like your question on and only ask it there unless you have a specific reason to address it to another community. ELU and ELL are similar enough that you should not really ask it in both places.

Comment: It gets worse. Liz's [video lesson](http://ieltsliz.com/ielts-writing-task-1-complex-sentence/) on complex sentences is posted on YouTube, but with restricted access, and Liz will be away until the autumn.

Comment: I think if only to give the poor reader a bit of a helping hand it might be considerate to drop in a comma or dash after **125** (and/or after **200**) in the first example. But only a pedant could think that was "grammatically required". The text is a *little* tortuous, but hardly excessively so.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your opinion of the below is solicited.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: There's no shame in being eclipsed by StoneyB if he puts his mind to a question! I'm somewhat awed to have to assume from his answer that he actually *watched* some if not *all* of [IELTS Writing Task 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YngqHl_BLOU) on Youtube. We are as nothing in the face of such dedication *and* mastery of the art of answering ELL questions! :) But I would have upvoted you quite happily if yours had been the only answer - even though I've only just read it a minute ago, I've already forgotten the "compound/complex" distinction - because in truth *I don't care!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Neither, frankly, do I. But many of our learners (and a few of our native schoolchildren, if they're taught anything at all) are taught with great earnestness that they *ought* to care; so it's mere courtesy to take it seriously before blowing it up.

Comment: Incidentally, Moris, I must tell you that the grammar and diction of your question are impeccable.

Comment: @StoneyB: Come now! Soon you'll be saying we have to give due deference to all those "never split an infinitive" and "don't end a sentence with a preposition" types! I say mock them to death, then dance on their graves! But *my* daddy couldn't tell you the difference between a noun and a verb, so obviously my background's a bit different. And sometimes I think he *ought* to know about things like that - he got little schooling, but he could have picked things up over the years if he'd cared enough.

Comment: Your first example is complex because it contains the subordinate dependent clause _deciding to start a vegetarian diet_. And the last one is complex because it contains the subordinate dependent clause _becoming vegetarian_. The other two are simple sentences.

Comment: @BillJ. i searched the definition of clause in the web, it says -Every clause has at least a subject and a verb. "Deciding to start vegetarian diet" has a verb but no subject. Same in "becoming vegetarian". See this link about "clause" definition : http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/clause.htm

Comment: One of the things that IELTS writing module emphasizes on is using complex sentence or complex structures (i think both are same thing). IELTS writing task 1 score/band emphasizes on four criteria: Task Achievement, Coherence and Cohesion, Lexical Resource, Grammatical Range and Accuracy. The last criterion "Grammatical Range and Accuracy" emphasizes on various things. In order to get band 7 in writing task 1 (the highest band is 9) , the official band descriptor says (in 'Grammar' criterion) - uses a variety of complex structures. To get 6 - 'uses a mix of simple and complex 
sentence forms'

Comment: The link for IELTS writing task 1 band descriptor: http://takeielts.britishcouncil.org/sites/default/files/IELTS_task_1_Writing_band_descriptors.pdf
Therefore, IELTS does give importance on using complex sentence structures.

Comment: @all the members. This link has a section about complex sentence. It says about dependent clause and gives examples, but 'nowhere' I found this "becoming vegetarian" as an example of subordinate/dependent clause.

Comment: Non-finite clauses are usually subjectless, as is "becoming vegetarian" but they are still clauses since they are headed by a verb. "Becoming vegetarian" has the non-finite verb "becoming" as head and the subject "the number of people" is recoverable from the noun phrase containing the clause.

Comment: In my previous comment, "This link has a section about complex sentence." refers to this link (i forgot to mention): http://www2.ivcc.edu/rambo/eng1001/sentences.htm

Comment: Well, if you don't believe the teacher on the video and you don't believe me, then that is up to you.

Comment: This is a new thing I have come across that there is a thing like 'non-finite clause'. So a 'non-finite clause' can ALSO be called a subordinate clause? According to what you said, the 1st and 4th sentence are complex sentences. NOT the 2nd and 3rd. I am a little surprised that I didn't find an example of complex sentence containing non-finite clause in the grammar websites I've looked upon so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43519/discussion-between-moris-and-billj).

Comment: "being prepared, he attempted the test" is a COMPLEX sentence as it has non-finite verb (being). Right?
In the same way - "I like to watch television" is a COMPLEX sentence because of having "like to" which is a non-finite verb.
please correct me if i am mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

These are not (as you observe) "complex sentences" in the sense in which the term was traditionally taught; they are merely "complicated" in various ways.

But the term "complex sentence", however you define it, doesn't provide any sort of useful category for learning or using the English language; we managed to write pretty good sentences for several hundred years before the term was invented around 1830<sup>†</sup>, and many of us who were forced to learn and apply the term have managed forget it and write pretty good sentences without once worrying about what category they belonged to.

So I hope that the IELTS doesn't ask you anything so irrelevant to assessing your mastery of the language as (for instance) "Which of the following sentences is/are complex?"

I suggest you ignore the terminology and focus on what **is** of value in IELTS Liz' video, which is her exposition of the variety of constructions through which any given thought can be expressed—and her very plausible suggestion<sup>‡</sup> that demonstrating your ability to use many of those constructions competently will enhance your score.

---

<sup>†</sup> According to [this site](http://dickhudson.com/sentence-classification/); but its modern significance doesn't seem to have been pinned down until 1863.
<sup>‡</sup> . . . meaning that ***I*** find it plausible; but I'm not familiar with the IELTS test and canons of grading, and anyone who is should feel free to correct what I have said.

Comment: The WWW is rife with sites which contain such statements as "‘Complex sentences are not actually very complex; they are just simple two or more simple sentences put together." (sic). I've deleted my answer, although I think it does provide useful guidance for someone hours away from an exam...

Comment: IELTS and TOEFL do not ask about such things. They consist of 4 parts: reading skill, listening skill, writing skill, and speaking skill. There is no specific question directly assesses the grammarian knowledge of the exam takers.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I think so, too; I'd just like to see you dissociate your advice from the traditional terminological categories, which I think are pretty useless. --My father was an English professor; when I brought the simple-compound-complex thing home in the fifth grade he spent an hour making crystal clear what it was about and told me to forget it once I was past the exam.

Comment: @Cardinal Thank you. I hoped that was the case, because those examiners seem to actually know something about the language besides the prejudices they were taught in school; but we see so many really bad exam questions around here I worried about the quality of my advice.

Comment: correction to my comment: "grammarian" is wrong there, it must be substituted by "grammar".

Comment: @Cardinal The IELTS writing skill portion does ask the testee to write a complex sentence, doesn't it? If not, why is that skill stressed in so many IELTS practice sites?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Of course it asks them to write essays, but I am sure that it does not ask "which one of these sentences are complex", ''cross out the complex sentence " or "what is the difference between attributive adjective and predicative adjective" and this sort of thing.

Comment: @P.E.Dant However, the referees and reviewers are native and can easily assess your grammar knowledge by checking your sentences, diversity of patterns ans structures and word choices. I am preparing for TOEFL myself. For example, in TOEFL, you must hand in two essays- independent essay and integrated essay ( you do this: read-listen-write). In fact, without knowing grammar it would be very challenging since you have to fulfill the tasks in a very limited time- there is no time for hesitation.

Comment: @Cardinal: Going by your posts here on ELL, I doubt TOEFL will give you any trouble! But it *is* an ambiguous statement. Are you preparing to *take* a test, or to become involved as a trainer?

Comment: @Cardinal What I can't seem to find out is whether one of the IELTS questions is of the form: "Given that we have 1: There is an English town. 2: Its population increased steadily from 75 to 200 between 2004 and 2007. 3. More and more of them eschew meat. Write a complex sentence which conveys these facts." I think that is the _meat_ of the OP's question here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you, I'm glad that you have positive veiw about my English. I think you went too far. I am preparing for taking the exam.

Comment: @P. E. Dant As far as I know, they wil not provide you with those examples but, they ask you to pharaphrase a ghraph or figure.

Comment: @Cardinal: You'll ace it (even if you have to look that one up! :) But idiomatically, *I am preparing **to take** the exam* is more natural, I would say.

Comment: The OP's first example is complex because it contains the subordinate dependent clause "deciding to start a vegetarian diet" (it modifies the NP "amount of people .."). And so is the last one since it contains the subordinate dependent clause "becoming vegetarian" (modifying the NP "the number of people").

Comment: @BillJ You and I call those clauses (my definition is 'a construction headed by a verb'), but in the Bad Old Days they would have been called participle *phrases*, not clauses, because lacking overt subjects they aren't 'closed'.

Comment: Yes, but here we are in 2016 when they are called (non-finite) clauses by almost everyone.

Comment: @BillJ "Almost everyone" is shorthand for "most scholars of English syntax", and I'm afraid that excludes many teachers of English. I'll give you dollars to doughnuts that it excludes **most** of those teachers of English whose stock in trade includes the simple-compound-complex categorization which scholars of English syntax have little use for. See *CGEL*, 45n.

Comment: Lol, but no it's not. The teacher on the video the OP watched certainly thinks the sentences are complex, The 2nd and 4th ones are definitely not, though, but I suspect the OP may have misunderstood something in the video. H&P's note is irrelevant since it merely debunks the whole notion of distinguishing simple, complex and compound sentences. The teachers at my language school always teach subjectless non-finites as clauses, not phrases - I insist on that.

Comment: @StoneyB. IELTS does emphasize on Grammatical Range i.e. sentence stuctures, using passive voice, using gerund etc. Go to this link of british council and you will find all about the marking criteria for IELTS writing task 1: http://takeielts.britishcouncil.org/sites/default/files/IELTS_task_1_Writing_band_descriptors.pdf

Comment: @BillJ I agree with you about clause/phrase. But do you have a use for the s-cd-cx categories? I've never seen what it was good for, either formally or pedagogically.

Comment: Sometimes the categorisation comes in useful when getting students to identify non-finite clauses, especially the trickier ones to identify like those functioning as post-modifiers in NPs.

Comment: @BillJ the teacher in the video clearly says that the sentences are "Complex"

Comment: @BillJ Hmm ... I'll ponder on that. Anyway, my point was that OP has almost certainly been taught under the Old Tradition, which holds that a  complex sentence is one which contains both independent and dependent clauses AND a "clause" is characterized by the presence of both a subject and a predicate -- which is why OP is puzzled by IELTS Liz' use of the term "complex" sentence for these utterances.

Comment: I have gone to several websites and none of them shows an example of complex sentence like in my post (the four sentences). Don't know why

Comment: Yes, but the OP asked about the examples used in the video, specifically why they are complex. I'm simply trying to answer that question.

Comment: @Moris I'm agreeing with the teacher about the 1st and 4th examples; they are complex; but the 2nd and 3rd examples are definitely simple sentences.

Comment: @StoneyB . I posted 4 sentences. The 1st and 4th sentences have 'not-finite clause'. But the 2nd and 3rd do Not have any. I am puzzled that why are they mentioned as complex sentences in the video.

2nd sentence: Between 2004 and 2007, the number of people increased steadily from about 75 to 200.

3rd sentence:  There was a steady increase in the number of people from about 75 to 200 between 2004 and 2007.

Comment: Moris, I'm pretty sure IELTS Liz is using the term "complex sentence" in a non-technical sense--you could paraphrase it "complicated sentence".  My advice is that you not get hung up on her idiosyncratic terminology--don't worry about what's complex and what's simple or what's a clause and what's a phrase. Concentrate instead on her practical demonstration of  'transforming' the sentence into different configurations.

Comment: @StoneyB, what u meant by 'idiosyncratic terminology' ? my English is far below your level lol

Comment: @BillJ what is the full form of NP ? is it 'noun phrase' ?

Comment: Yes, NP is an abbreviation for noun phrase. The other abbreviations are: PP = preposition phrase; AdjP = adjective phrase; AdvP = adverb phrase; DP = determinative phrase; VP = verb phrase

Comment: @Moris I mean that she uses the terms "complex sentence" and (by inference) "clause" in senses of her own--they're not like either the traditional meaning or the meaning in which BillJ and I use these terms.